# Python Process Multiple PDF file from Multiple location at same time

Tags: python-3.x

I have processing 1500 PDF File On a daily basis from three different locations. My Problem is while running a code it processes folder 1 first then folder 2 then folder 3.

I want it to process all folders at the same time, for example, they process 5 files from folder 1 and 3 files from folder 2 and 4 files from folder 3.
So we can't wait until the completion of folder 1.some time folder1 have 500 files which mean I need to wait till the program process all files of folder 1 then it processes folder2

I try threading but not working, it processes folder Serial means it process folder1 files first after finishing folder1 file it processes folder2. But I want to process foler1 and folder 2 files at the same time.
I will explain a little bit about the below code, I have 3 folder location which has PDF files  and I have the main function which response for converting PDF to PS, I am calling function in three different thread with 3 location

```
inputpath1 = "/121rawfile/FTP HotFolder"
inputpath2 = "/121rawfile/FTP Download File"
inputpath3 = "/121rawfile/Olive"
## define function with variable filename and the format of the timestamp
def timeStamped(filename, fmt='%m-%d-%y-{filename}'):
   os.chdir("/PDF_Flattening")
   return datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(filename=filename)
filename=timeStamped("log_file_9.log")
logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",level = logging.DEBUG)   
while True:
 try:
   t1=threading.Thread(target=main(inputpath1),args=(inputpath1,))
   t1.start()
   t2=threading.Thread(target=main(inputpath2),args=(inputpath2,))
   t2.start()
   t3=threading.Thread(target=main(inputpath3),args=(inputpath3,))
   t3.start()
   raise Exception("Error simulated!")
   except Exception as e :
     logging.error("failed")
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly didn't work with threading?
Can you paste the error you get in the question?

Comment: No error in threading I mean it processes folder Serial means it process folder1 files first after finishing folder1 file it processes folder2. But I want to process foler1 and folder 2 files at the same time@NirO

Comment: you might want to use multiprocessing rather than multithreading. Try looking into the multiprocessing library

Comment: can you give some example because i new in python@NirO

Comment: https://realpython.com/async-io-python/ could also be interesting, depending on speed pc, and amount of processing.

Answer (score 0):

CPython (the standard python implementation) has something called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock); the GIL prevents two threads from executing simultaneously in the same program. . For CPU bound tasks and truly parallel execution, we can use the multiprocessing module.
A basic example on how to use multiprocessing module:
( [python doc link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html))

```
from multiprocessing import Process 
    def f(name):
        print('hello', name)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

For more info you can refer :
[link](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python)